# how are server side script safe and hidden which are written with Node js?

Tags: node.js

First check this code which is written in node js and has used `sql` module on it.

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'me',
password : 'secret',
database : 'my_db'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
 if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

Above code have some private information like database name,user,password and `sql` query too.I am not new at `node.js` but not that expert on it.If a script which have been written on `Node.js` will save in `.js` format and what if it contain server side script too?I mean how can it be safe/hidden like .php do?

Comment: You should be make sure that server should not serve any .js file from your code directory. Although if you want to server public static content like .js and css, then you can serve for that only directory using express.static. If they are not served to client then they are safe. Only you are going to access it.

Comment: thanks @HirenS. now I understood.

Answer (score 1):

Server side codes (NodeJS, PHP etc) are executed on your server and only the output of the executed code is sent to the browser or client.

Incase of `NodeJS` script above, it is executed on your node server. However, with the `NodeJS` you will need to make sure that those directories (your source code) are not served as static contents.